# backbone js, JSON string is not stored properly

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Here is the complete code:

```
var picTempJSON = JSON.stringify(pictures);

//code to update model

usersCollection.fetch({

  success : function() {

    var getModel = usersCollection.where(checkFBAccountIdJSON);

      //console.log(PersonJson);

    for (var i in getModel) {

      getModel[i].set('pictures', picTempJSON);

      getModel[i].save();

    }

    console.log(usersCollection.toJSON());

  },

  error : function() {
      // something is wrong..
  }

});
```

Input string:

```
["xxxx.jpg","xxxx.jpg","xxxxx.jpg"]
```

Output String:

```
pictures = "[\"xxxx.jpg\",\"xxxx_n.jpg\",\"xxxxx.jpg\"]";
```

the problem I have is that the input string does not reflect the output string (or the string stored in the model), this will cause problems later down the line when I have to recovert the string into a JSON object as it is invalid JSON due to the backslashes

Comment: do you need `pictures` to be a string or an array, when you are requesting them after `usersCollection.toJSON()`?

Comment: need it as an array, but because i have stringified it when storing it inside the model, i cant foreach it properly as it is treating the output string after getting it (which has no back slashes) as a string

Answer (score 0):

if you really have to store it as a string in a model, you can either call

```
var pictures = JSON.parse(model.get('pictures'));
```

to get the data or rewrite model's `toJSON` method and call `JSON.parse(...)` in it, so while iterating over collection each model will have everything prepared

```
var AnyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  //...
  toJSON: function() {
    return {
       //...
       'pictures': JSON.parse(this.get('pictures'))
       //...
    }
  }
  //...
});
```